# Preparing and executing SQLite Statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have been trying to puts some executed statements after I prepare them. The purpose of this is to sanitize my data inputs, which I have never done before. I followed the steps [here](http://zetcode.com/db/sqliteruby/bind/), but I am not getting the result I want.

Here's what I have:

```
require 'sqlite3'

$db = SQLite3::Database.open "congress_poll_results.db"

def rep_pull(state)
  pull = $db.prepare("SELECT name, location FROM congress_members WHERE location = ?")
  pull.bind_param 1, state
  puts pull.execute
end

rep_pull("MN")

=> #<SQLite3::ResultSet:0x2e69e00>
```

What I am expecting is a list of reps in MN, but instead I just get "SQLite3::ResultSet:0x2e69e00" thing.

What am I missing here? Thanks very much.

Comment: I'd recommend not try writing directly to any particular DBM. Instead, decouple your code from a particular flavor of SQL by using an ORM such as Sequel, DataMapper or Active Record. That way, you code using the ORM, which then generates the appropriate queries for the DBM you're using. If you need to migrate to another DBM you make a minor tweak to your configuration and, if written correctly, the rest of your code remains the same. I recommend using [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net). Look at its opening page and you can see how easy it is to talk to SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
def rep_pull(state)
  pull = $db.prepare("SELECT name, location FROM congress_members WHERE location = ?")
  pull.bind_param 1, state
  pull.execute do |row|
     p row
  end
end
```